# Whether every TCP packet have a Ack Reply?

Tags: tcp, network, protocol-theory

The TCP Acknowledgements you see in the diagram's green arrows, have ACK numbers separated by `3000`(two `1500 bytes`).

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I have a question, why the Ack number is separated by two packets? Or is it just convenient for the drawing? Should every TCP packet have a Ack reply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a standard TCP feature (see [RFC 1122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122#page-96)) called Delayed ACK. The spec says you can wait before ACKing a packet but :

- You shouldn't wait more than 500ms
- You should ack every other packet if you are receiving full size packets.

It cuts down on the number of ACKs that you need to send.